# Link not opening in system browser in ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am in process of making an ionic application and trying to open a link in app using `cordova.InAppBrowser` but I get this error when I click it

```
Application Error
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///android_assets/www/(item.url))
```

MY Code

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in object.torrents" class="button-bar bar-dark" >
  <a onclick="window.open('(item.url)', '_system' );" class="button">Open</a>

</div>
```

Comment: what is `(item.url)` there?

Comment: i am fetching url from a json

Comment: Are you sure item.url is giving the correct url, because in the error msg it seems url is not valid

Comment: yes it gives correct url check out this plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/EbdFRHuVMCQY0SV7fqZS?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Html Code 
<a ng-click = openUrl(item.url); class="button">button</a>

js Code

$scope.openUrl = function(url) {
    //alert(url);
    window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the angular syntax for object property retrieval.

Try this.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in object.torrents" class="button-bar bar-dark" >
  <a onclick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open('{{item.url}}', '_system');" class="button">Open</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Ready where? In js file

Comment: yeah just make sure that the device ready event is called. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#installation

Comment: i have not included any code in js regarding inappbrowser

Comment: you don't have to include any code just make sure the device is ready for device plugins before you call them.

Comment: .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
           cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

Comment: @pawanjee Which plugin are you using?

Comment: Cordova inappbrowser with ionic 1

Comment: try with this. `cordova.InAppBrowser.open('{{item.url}}', '_blank');`

Comment: @pawanjee Its strange, it should work, try using this in an angular wrapped function. like `ng-click="callCordovaBrowser()"` and define a function in the controller like `$scope.callCordovaBrowser = function(){cordova.InAppBrowser.open('{{item.url}}', '_blank');}`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-click` instead of `onclick`